# Kafka Exactly-once selection Or Dedup in Consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

Goal: make messages only consume once.

Plan 1: Enable Kafka Exactly-once semantics

Plan 2: No Exactly-once setting, but add dedup work in consumer.

Which one is better or each pros and cons?

Comment: By default, latest Kafka clients already enable idempotency

Comment: Yes, exactly. So is it better to directly use Kafka idempotency? Is it unnecessary to have another level of dedup in consumer?

Comment: more moving parts = more maintenance + you are reinventing the wheel

Comment: Thanks, I should never re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka's built-in idempotency is only per-producer-request. If you will write client code that sends events with same data across multiple requests (for example, constantly scanning a database table, file, website, etc), then yes, you need de-duplication code on the consumer side and/or the producer side to filter-out that data.